# twitter bootstrap ".input-append" not work with popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

When I use input append and popover at the same time then popover not working, but when I remove the appended input (by removing the input-append class) then it works.
Here is my code:

```
<span class="input-append">

                <button class="span2" id="filter" type="text" name="filter" placeholder="Type your filter">itest</button>
          <button class="btn" id="filterSubmits">Go</button>
</span>
<script>
jQuery(function() {


        $('#filter').attr('data-title', 'Search tips').
            attr('data-content', 'Search format: -|+').
            attr('data-placement', 'bottom').
            attr('data-trigger', 'focus');

        $('#filter').popover('show');
})
</script>
```

Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the css for input-append, you'd see that it sets font-size to 0. Adding the following style will fix your issue:

```
.popover {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```